# How to implement workaround for ESRI BUG-000119907, arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to write an ArcPy script, within an ArcPy toolbox and the arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management command is failing. as per bug report: https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDExOTkwNw==

The workaround described however does not make sense to me.

> To fix this issue: 1. After adding the arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrfile) Python command, add the arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, layer) parameter. 2. Save the script. 3. ArcGIS Pro > Catalog Pane > Toolbox > Right click Script > Properties. 4. Properties Window > Parameter Tab > Add a new parameter of type Layer, and set it to derived output

The **layer** is already set as a parameter of the script:

````
        param5 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="TOP_10_LYR",
            name ="TOP_10_LYR",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Derived",
            direction="Output")
        param5.value = "TOP_10_LYR" ```
-------------------------
``` arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(TOP_10_LYR, TOP10_LAYER)```
------------------------------------------------
 arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(TOP_10_LYR, TOP10_LAYER) <-- not working!!
````

I have tried adding the line arcpy.SetParameterAsText(2, TOP_10_LYR)  after the ApplySymbology command but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Interestingly the first time I use ApplySymbologyFromLayer it does work, but not layers I create after that. Note that the layers are all new feature classes.

Comment: Without fully understanding the bug, it's possible that workaround doesn't apply to your situation. The workaround infers this is for a script tool. You're working with a Python toolbox. Does the bug/workaround apply to you? Maybe? Maybe not. Just pointing out this difference incase things don't work as expected.

Comment: I think I may have found a workaround here: https://community.esri.com/message/917721-re-adding-feature-class-and-applying-symbology-in-arcgis-pro-using-arcpy?commentID=917721#comment-917721?q=BUG-000119907

Comment: Still a bug, recently logged again as a separate issue, just for Python here:https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEwODQ5Nw==

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python but I think I may have (somewhat accidentally) found a workaround for those encountering this error within a Python Toolbox. I saved my output symbology template (.lyrx) in the same folder as my Python Toolbox. After defining my parameters in the getParameterInfo(self) method of the tool, I added the 2 lines in the attached image:

[image: Code Snippet]

When I ran the tool, the correct symbology was applied to the output. This worked on my own laptop and my University's remote server, so I feel confident that it's a viable solution.

The difference that I've noticed is that I applied they symbology in the getParameterInfo method rather than the execute method of the tool.

Note: I ran the tool countless times (and received countless errors) over a few days when trying to update my output symbology. During my trial and error, I do recall receiving an "Attribute Error: 'str' has no attribute 'symbology'". I still don't understand why it "output_param.symbology" worked this time and not previous times, but like I said, I'm new to programming.

Comment: Please add the  script as text, not picture.

Comment: Very Interesting! I'm using ArcPro 2.8.1 now and I have got it working but not for all of my LYRX files. I have found it has some issues with Continous Colour schemes vs Discrete (Discrete works), Also that creating the Lyrx from a Layer name different to the Layer name I want to apply it to helps.